# Geoserver & Leaflet GetFeatureInfo

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geoserver, wms

I want to Disable the WMS getFeatureInfo popup of Leaflet when I click outside the wms layer[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QcNK.png) I use this plugin  https://gist.github.com/rclark/6908938

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your function to:

```
 getFeatureInfo: function (evt) {
    // Make an AJAX request to the server and hope for the best
    var url = this.getFeatureInfoUrl(evt.latlng),
      showResults = L.Util.bind(this.showGetFeatureInfo, this);
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      success: function (data, status, xhr) {
        var err = typeof data === 'string' ? null : data;
        //Fix for blank popup window
        var doc = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(data, "text/html"); 
        if (doc.body.innerHTML.trim().length > 0)
          showResults(err, evt.latlng, data);
      },
      error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        showResults(error);
      }
    });
  },
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/rclark/6908938#gistcomment-2277325

Comment: that's exactly what i want thanks for your quick reply